# Failed to download Ubuntu One

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one, error-handling

I am trying to install **Ubuntu One** but here showing an error message. [image: Error message]

I've no idea what does it mean and how to handle it.  Anybody please help me.

Comment: Please remove the Malformed line "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian" from `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Comment: Then follow https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-setup-ubuntu-one-on-ubuntu-1204-lts/

Answer (score 0):

That means you have wrong line inside your `sources.list` or `sources.list.d` files. Your VirtualBox is non-free version so it does not have sources shipped with it.

### To fix error

Search for

```
deb-src http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian maverick contrib
```

inside `/etc/apt/sources.list` and comment it by `#` sign.

### Alternate way

Look into *Software & Sources* in Configuration. Show *Additional* tab and uncheck sources for VirtualBox. Here is the screenshot:
[image: screenshot]
Notice that VistualBox sources are unchecked.

### After all

Run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and this will fix the error.